# Oracle stored procedure fails to generate csv file - ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buff

Tags: oracle, csv, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a procedure  that reads value from the table and generate a csv file and mail them . The procedure was working fine until I entered  new entries in DB and it fails to generate CSV file after that. The procedure is throwing an exception " ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buff" and I have tried to print the value that is read from table to check if it was working properly .

By printing the values I could see that one of  the new entry is not being read properly and I believe this could be the reason for the issue .

[image]

I have checked for the reason why the values after O Brien being printed in new line and I could see that that value sits in the table like this with cursor on new line :

[image]

Error that got printed in log :

Error raised: ORA-06512: at "UPDATER.mypro", line 50

- ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

Here is my code :

```
create or replace PROCEDURE         mypro AS 

O_ErrorCode  Number;
O_ErrorDesc  VARCHAR2(100);
l_clob2  VARCHAR2 (32767);
l_attach_text2 VARCHAR2 (32767);
l_attach_text_h2 VARCHAR2 (32767);
v_From VARCHAR2(280) := ' abc';
v_Recipient VARCHAR2(280) := 'efggg';
v_Subject VARCHAR2(280) := 'Entry & Details';
v_Mail_Host VARCHAR2(230) := 'abcd';
v_Mail_Conn utl_smtp.Connection;
crlf VARCHAR2(200) := chr(13)||chr(10);
FC_SV_STATUS_DESC VARCHAR2(100) := 'open';



CURSOR c2 IS 
   select FC_CA_RECORD_ID,to_char(FC_CA_INPUT_DATE ,'DD-MM-YY')as FC_CA_INPUT_DATE,FC_CA_PAYER,FC_CA_AMOUNT,FC_CA_TYPE,FC_CA_PAYEE,FC_CA_ADD_REMARKS,FC_CA_COMMENTS,FC_CA_ACC_NO,FC_CA_POLICY_NO,to_char(FC_CA_BRANCHCONF_DATE ,'DD-MM-YY')as FC_CA_BRANCHCONF_DATE,FC_CA_CONFIRMED_BY,to_char(FC_CA_SHEETUPDATE_DATE ,'DD-MM-YY')as FC_CA_SHEETUPDATE_DATE,to_char(FC_CA_MAILUPDATE_DATE ,'DD-MM-YY')as FC_CA_MAILUPDATE_DATE,to_char(FC_CA_UPLOAD_TIME ,'DD-MM-YY')as FC_CA_UPLOAD_TIME,FC_CA_UPLOAD_ID FROM Abcd where  FC_CA_STATUS =1 ;

BEGIN

  
l_attach_text_h2 :=
'ID ,INPUT DATE ,PAYER ,AMOUNT ,TYPE ,PAYEE - SORT CODE & BANK ACCOUNT NO ,ADDITIONAL REMARKS ,COMMENTS ,ACCOUNT NUMBER ,POLICY NUMBER ,DATE OF BRANCH CONFIRMATION ,CONFIRMED BY ,SHEETUPDATE DATE ,MAILUPDATE DATE ,DATE-TIME ,USER ID ,STATUS ';

FOR employee_rec2 in c2

LOOP

l_attach_text2 :=      '"' || 
employee_rec2.FC_CA_RECORD_ID        || '","' ||
employee_rec2.FC_CA_INPUT_DATE       || '","' ||
employee_rec2.FC_CA_PAYER            || '","' ||
employee_rec2.FC_CA_AMOUNT           || '","' ||
employee_rec2.FC_CA_TYPE             || '","' ||
employee_rec2.FC_CA_PAYEE            || '","' ||
employee_rec2.FC_CA_ADD_REMARKS      || '","' ||
employee_rec2.FC_CA_COMMENTS         || '","' ||
employee_rec2.FC_CA_ACC_NO           || '","' ||
employee_rec2.FC_CA_POLICY_NO        || '","' ||
employee_rec2.FC_CA_BRANCHCONF_DATE  || '","' ||
employee_rec2.FC_CA_CONFIRMED_BY     || '","' ||
employee_rec2.FC_CA_SHEETUPDATE_DATE || '","' ||
employee_rec2.FC_CA_MAILUPDATE_DATE  || '","' ||
employee_rec2.FC_CA_UPLOAD_TIME      || '","' ||
employee_rec2.FC_CA_UPLOAD_ID        || '","' ||
FC_SV_STATUS_DESC                    || '"'   ||chr(13);

l_clob2 := l_clob2||chr(10)||l_attach_text2;

END LOOP;

l_clob2 := l_attach_text_h2 ||chr(13)|| l_clob2;

DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(' entries processing  completed...');

v_Mail_Conn := utl_smtp.Open_Connection(v_Mail_Host, 25);

utl_smtp.Helo(v_Mail_Conn, v_Mail_Host);

utl_smtp.Mail(v_Mail_Conn, v_From);

utl_smtp.Rcpt(v_Mail_Conn, v_Recipient);

utl_smtp.Data(v_Mail_Conn,
'Date: ' || to_char(sysdate, 'Dy, DD Mon YYYY hh24:mi:ss') || crlf ||
'From: ' || v_From || crlf ||
'Subject: '|| v_Subject || crlf ||
'To: ' || v_Recipient || crlf ||

'MIME-Version: 1.0'|| crlf || -- Use MIME mail standard
'Content-Type: multipart/mixed;'|| crlf ||
' boundary="-----SECBOUND"'|| crlf ||
crlf ||

'-------SECBOUND'|| crlf ||
'Content-Type: text/plain;'|| crlf ||
'Content-Transfer_Encoding: 7bit'|| crlf ||
crlf ||
'Please find the following in the attachments :'|| crlf || -- Message body
'Entry details'|| crlf ||
crlf ||

'-------SECBOUND'|| crlf ||
'Content-Type: text/plain;'|| crlf ||
' name="myfile.csv"'|| crlf ||
'Content-Transfer_Encoding: 8bit'|| crlf ||
'Content-Disposition: attachment;'|| crlf ||
' filename="myfile.csv"'|| crlf ||
crlf ||
 l_clob2  || crlf || -- Content of attachment
crlf ||

'-------SECBOUND--' -- End MIME mail
);

utl_smtp.Quit(v_mail_conn);

DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('mail send  completed...');

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
         O_ErrorCode := SQLCODE;
         O_ErrorDesc := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 64);
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(O_ErrorCode);
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(O_ErrorDesc);
       SYSTEM.intranet_utils.intranet_log_errors
                                   (
                                    'Exception',
                                    SYSTEM.intranet_utils.intranet_get_errmsg
                                   );

        dba_utils.dba_log_batch ( 'Complete', 'Erred');
        system.intranet_utils.INTRANET_LOG_ERRORS('procedure mypro',
        system.intranet_utils.INTRANET_GET_ERRMSG, 'Error in mypro');
END mypro;
```

Can anyone tell me how can I fix this issue in my code  and how can properly print the errors in logs ??

Comment: Your current exception handler is calling some code which you haven't shared, presumably this is logging the errors somewhere else (hopefully in an autonomous transaction). I would suggest you end it with an additional `raise;` statement so that the caller can see the error too. Did you mean for `l_clob2` to not be a `clob`?

Comment: @AndrewSayer  .. I am able to get the following error now  ..... ORA-20000: ORU-10027: buffer overflow, limit of 20000 bytes

Comment: @AndrewSayer  "  Did you mean for l_clob2 to not be a clob?   " ................  by this you mean to change type of l_clob2  ? .

Comment: I mean naming the column like clob suggest you probably meant for it to a `clob` data type, if you do change this you'll need to change some other variables too.

Comment: I would like to have it of type clob .... anyway I dont think  if it has  connection to my issue ... currently the error after removing dbms_output is  ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buff

Comment: Can you format source code?

Comment: after removing dbms_output  ....i got the exact issue  Error raised: ORA-06512: at "UPDATER.mypro", line 50
 - ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

Answer (score 0):

The reason it worked before but stopped working is most probably that you reached the buffer value for dbms_output. The default buffer size is 20000 (check [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/arpls/DBMS_OUTPUT.html#GUID-DCF44F7C-A888-497D-910A-9E1871C3CF7E)) and when that is exceeded the error `ORU-10027` is thrown. I suggest you remove those calls - for this reason no production code should have calls to dbms_output.

Comment: removing dbms output helped me find the exact issue ..... Error raised: ORA-06512: at "UPDATER.mypro", line 50
 - ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

Answer (score 0):

the second parameter on procedure "data" in package "utl_smtp" is of type VARCHAR2 so the limit is 32767 bytes.

for large data you must use
open_data
write_data
close_data

read documentation

Comment: thanks but ....it doesnt solve my issue ... Error raised: ORA-06512: at "UPDATER.mypro", line 50
 - ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small